# Python Split String at First Non-Alpha Character

Tags: python, string, split

Say I have strings such as `'ABC)D.'` or `'AB:CD/'`. How can I split them at the first non-alphabetic character to end up with `['ABC', 'D.']` and `['AB', 'CD/']`? Is there a way to do this without regex?

Comment: You can use [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)

Comment: See also the `before_and_after()` recipe.

Comment: Why not use regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Barmar's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73792846/python-split-string-at-first-non-alpha-character/73792939#comment130303007_73792846)'s worked best for me. The other answers had near the same execution time but I chose the former for readability.

```
from itertools import takewhile

str = 'ABC)D.'
alphStr = ''.join(takewhile(lambda x: x.isalpha(), str))

print(alphStr) # Outputs 'ABC'
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to find the location of the first non-alphabetic character:

```py
def split_at_non_alpha(s):
    try:
        split_at = next(i for i, x in enumerate(s) if not x.isalpha())
        return s[:split_at], s[split_at+1:]
    except StopIteration: # if not found
        return (s,)

print(split_at_non_alpha('ABC)D.')) # ('ABC', 'D.')
print(split_at_non_alpha('AB:CD/')) # ('AB', 'CD/')
print(split_at_non_alpha('.ABCD')) # ('', 'ABCD')
print(split_at_non_alpha('ABCD.')) # ('ABCD', '')
print(split_at_non_alpha('ABCD')) # ('ABCD',)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop

```
a = 'AB$FDWRE'
i = 0
while i<len(a) and a[i].isalpha():
    i += 1

>>> a[:i]
'AB'
>>> a[i:]
'$FDWRE'
```

Comment: It'd be more Pythonic to use a for-loop: `for i, c in enumerate(a): if not c.isalpha(): break`. Then, if you wanted, it'd be easy to add an `else` clause to raise a `ValueError`.

Answer (score 1):

With `for loop`, `enumerate`, and string indexing:

```py
def first_non_alpha_splitter(word):
    for index, char in enumerate(word):
        if not char.isalpha():
            break
    return [word[:index], word[index+1:]]
```

**The result**

```py
first_non_alpha_splitter('ABC)D.')
# Output: ['ABC', 'D.']

first_non_alpha_splitter('AB:CD/')
# Output: ['AB', 'CD/']
```